# How to decode a jsonpickle file in python?

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I am making a D&D text-based game and wanted to make a save progress function where python would save a particular function that I made (such as episode 01) and would load the progress when user calls it. I am trying to use jsonpickle to do so, but am unable to load the file since it is not printing anything even though there is data in the file and is encoded in jsonpickle. Here is the code:

```
def load_game():
    """Load game state from a predefined savegame location
    and return the game state contained in that savegame.
    """
    with open("savegame.json", 'r') as savegame:
        state = jsonpickle.decode(savegame.read())
    return state


def save_game():
    global game_state
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'w') as savegame:
        savegame.write(jsonpickle.encode(game_state))
```

This is what is stored in my file:

```
{"py/function": "__main__.scene1"}
```

Comment: I don't understand; you say that you are not able to create a load file and at the same time you show what is in that file.

Comment: The data is in the file but i'm not able to call/retrieve it

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with `load_game()`?

Comment: It is not doing anything and is just ending the program. Any suggestions? Should I do anything with variable state ?

Comment: Do you mean that it raises an exception? In that case, yes, I have a suggestion: show the full traceback ([edit] the question to include it).

Comment: are you even calling `load_game` anywhere?  what does the calling code look like?

Comment: yes i'm calling load_game. It is only showing me the source of saved file 

PS C:\Users\_________\Downloads>